# changing date time format

Tags: c#, datetime

Hi I am trying to change my input date time format to a specific format like `"yyyy/MM/dd"`
But it changes to `"yyyy-MM-dd"` I don't know why.
Here is my code.

```
string format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text);
string idate = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: question asked a minute ago, already got 2 Answers with 5 up votes. Are you guys sitting together? :)

Answer (score 5):

Just supply `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

```
string idate = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It is considering your [DateTime separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) based on your current culture. Which in your case seems to be `-`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string idate = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Read: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator):

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate
>   localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` property of the current or specified
>   culture....

So `/` is replaced by your current culture's date-separator otherwise.